# To get a certain function I have to reflect the other one using the x axis and then shift it up 3 values. Represent that analytically

Tags: calculus

> The following picture shows $h(x)$ and $g(x)$:
>
> [image]
>
> Which of the following is true?
>
> [image]

I think that to get from g to h I have to replect g horizontaly and then shift it up by 3, because the asymptote becomes $y=-1$. So I think the solution is B), but my book states it's A. What did I do wrong?

Comment: B has to be correct

Comment: I also agree that B is correct.

Comment: Me too. Take $h(-10)$ as an example. It will be a little less than 2. (A) and (C) both give big values for $g(10)$, so they can't be right. In (B) and (D) $-g(-10)$ is a little smaller then -1. So 3 must be added to get from $\approx -1$ to $\approx 2$.